# how can i get 180 total on my table with select query

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, sum

how can i get 180 total with select. if Cat column number is 5
id is real id
mainid is subid

[image: select]

Comment: This question cannot be answered in its present state. Post your code and db schema.

Comment: Google "mysql aggregate functions" and also "WHERE" clause as well as comparisons.

Comment: I sent a image here

Comment: and what do you want us to do with an image; post it on FB maybe?

Comment: @nFnK, that image isn't helpful. Do you expect us to magically understand what your arrows mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: I wrote a answer

Comment: OP doesn't want to be helped, doesn't reply to questions, doesn't clarify, we'd all better ignore this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all. But I mean, really totally unclear, and even points us away from the real question.

Yet I think I get what you mean because of the picture, ignoring the text you wrote.

You will need:

```
SELECT SUM(total) FROM `table` 
WHERE cat=5 
   OR (mainId>0 AND EXISTS 
        (SELECT id FROM `table` T2 WHERE table.mainId=T2.id AND T2.cat=5))
```

Of course, replace `table` by the table name

Comment: To be clear: I Sum all the totals from records  with cat=5 or linked records with cat=5. It probably would be quicker with a left join wth itself.

Comment: It would help if you tell what goes wrong. Or what you exactly want. It almost looks like you do not want to be helped...